# Quit program on 'q' character

Tags: c++, console-application

I don't know how to make a program which exit on pressing 'q' character.
I'm doing this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
double arg;
char c;

while (c!= 'q' && c != 'Q')
{
    cout << "Please enter a number x (q = program quit) : " << endl;
    cin >> arg;

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}


return 0;
```

}

Program doesn't exit on 'q' or 'Q'. It's just keep asking about "Please enter a number x (q = program quit) : ". How shall I do that ? Thanks

Comment: `arg` is a `double`. `double` can't hold `q` or `Q`. Read into something that can store numbers and letters (hint: a string).

Comment: You never update your `c` variable so it can never equal "Q" or "q"

Comment: How can I convert double to char ?

Comment: `cin >> c;` before while and `cin >> c;` where you have `cin >> arg;`

Comment: no - it doesn't work like I want. I don't want to read anything from the console before asking "Please enter a number ..."

Comment: @DearDeer make a do while then

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. I need number form the console to operate it inside the loop and character from the console as well to have opportunity to quit on 'q'. I need some conversion from double to char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not read "c" in code.

Comment: How can I convert double to char then ? I need that double variable as well

Comment: you can read string simply if it is "q" or "Q" then break otherwise use string stream to convert string to float like this

istringstream ss(str);

ss >> arg;

Answer (score 0):

@user1627167 thanks. It works. Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double arg;
    string s;

    while (s != "q" && s != "Q")
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number x (q = program quit) : " << endl;
        cin >> s;

        istringstream ss(s);
        ss >> arg;

        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```